# How to Convert Curl command to php for -i -t option

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I would like to convert below curl command into php and i tried to convert from https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ but its not converting properly. How can i set `<myobject>` in php curl? that i am not getting. Can anyone help me in this?

**`curl -i -T <myobject> -X PUT -H "X-Auth-Token: <token>" <storage url>`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to use curl to upload a file...

[Example](http://code.iamkate.com/php/sending-files-using-curl/)

```
// initialise the curl request
$request = curl_init('http://example.com/');

// send a file
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt(
    $request,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    array(
      'file' => '@' . realpath('example.txt')
    ));

// output the response
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo curl_exec($request);

// close the session
curl_close($request);
```

Comment: Working but need to set PUT method instead of POST